# Extending smooth functions on submanifolds with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

In Professor Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd edition, in the section
at the end of Chapter 5 on Submanifolds with Boundary, he states (just before
Proposition 5.49 on page 121)

> Many (though not all) of the earlier results in this chapter have analogues for
> submanifolds with boundary.

He then goes on to state a Proposition and two Theorems which are of that type. But absent
is any mention of whether or not the Extension Lemma for Functions on Submanifolds
(Lemma 5.34) holds in some form for submanifolds with boundary, nor are submanifolds
with boundary mentioned in the associated Problem 5-18, which has to do with converses
of Lemma 5.34.

My question is whether or not there are versions of Lemma 5.34 and Problem 5-18 that
apply to submanifolds with boundary. If so, are they just simple restatements with
submanifold replaced by submanifold with boundary, or is there something more needed?

Comment: Did you come up with an answer to this question?

Comment: @Juliane Unfortunately, I have not seen an answer nor have I discovered one on my own.